# Google Colab CUDA out of memory

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I am running a colab notebook "Disco Diffusion", it is a text to image ML algo. I am trying to render but I get a runtime error:

CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 960.00 MiB (GPU 0; 15.78 GiB total capacity; 14.11 GiB already allocated; 158.75 MiB free; 14.14 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is allocated memory, try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation. See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF

Now, if I render with small dimensions, it works perfectly fine. I tried to upgrade my GCE VM and I am still getting the same error.

**Here is the code:**

```
https://colab.research.google.com/github/alembics/disco-diffusion/blob/main/Disco_Diffusion.ipynb
```

Answer (score 0):

What GPU do you use for running the notebook? If it is a K80, that might be why as K80 has lesser RAM.
When you try to run the notebook too, it shows the following warning

> Notebook requires high RAM
> This notebook was authored in a high RAM runtime environment and may require
> more resources than are allocated in the version of Colab that is free of
> charge. If you encounter errors, you may want to check out Colab Pro.
> Blockquote

I would suggest using a GPU with more RAM if that is available to you, or you could try reducing the image resolution.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting this error for a combination of:

- The batch size is too big
- The images have too high resolution, witch makes the dataset too large
- The model you're using is too heavy due to the input shape

The only solutions would be to get Colab Pro or try to deal with the 3 problems I mentioned earlier.